# RedBlackTree Comparable

Tags: java

i am trying to understand the code below which constructs a red black tree.

package modules;

```
     import java.util.Comparator;
   // RedBlackTree class
//
// CONSTRUCTION: with a negative infinity sentinel
//
// ******************PUBLIC OPERATIONS*********************
// void insert( x )       --> Insert x
// void remove( x )       --> Remove x (unimplemented)
// Comparable find( x )   --> Return item that matches x
// Comparable findMin( )  --> Return smallest item
// Comparable findMax( )  --> Return largest item
// boolean isEmpty( )     --> Return true if empty; else false
// void makeEmpty( )      --> Remove all items
// void printTree( )      --> Print tree in sorted order

/**
 * Implements a red-black tree.
 * Note that all "matching" is based on the compareTo method.
 * @author Mark Allen Weiss
 */
public class RedBlackTree
{
    /**
     * Construct the tree.
     * @param negInf a value less than or equal to all others.
     */
    public RedBlackTree( Comparable negInf )
    {
        header      = new RedBlackNode( negInf );
        header.left = header.right = nullNode;
    }

    /**
     * Insert into the tree. Does nothing if item already present.
     * @param item the item to insert.
     */
    public void insert( Comparable item )
    {
        current = parent = grand = header;
        nullNode.element = item;

        while( current.element.compareTo( item ) != 0 )
        {
            great = grand; grand = parent; parent = current;
            current = item.compareTo( current.element ) < 0 ?
                         current.left : current.right;

                // Check if two red children; fix if so
            if( current.left.color == RED && current.right.color == RED )
                 handleReorient( item );
        }

            // Insertion fails if already present
        if( current != nullNode )
            return;
        current = new RedBlackNode( item, nullNode, nullNode );

            // Attach to parent
        if( item.compareTo( parent.element ) < 0 )
            parent.left = current;
        else
            parent.right = current;
        handleReorient( item );
    }

    /**
     * Remove from the tree.
     * Not implemented in this version.
     * @param x the item to remove.
     */
    public void remove( Comparable x )
    {
        System.out.println( "Remove is not implemented" );
    }

    /**
     * Find the smallest item  the tree.
     * @return the smallest item or null if empty.
     */
    public Comparable findMin( )
    {
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            return null;

        RedBlackNode itr = header.right;

        while( itr.left != nullNode )
            itr = itr.left;

        return itr.element;
    }

    /**
     * Find the largest item in the tree.
     * @return the largest item or null if empty.
     */
    public Comparable findMax( )
    {
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            return null;

        RedBlackNode itr = header.right;

        while( itr.right != nullNode )
            itr = itr.right;

        return itr.element;
    }

    /**
     * Find an item in the tree.
     * @param x the item to search for.
     * @return the matching item or null if not found.
     */
    public Comparable find( Comparable x )
    {
        nullNode.element = x;
        current = header.right;

        for( ; ; )
        {
            if( x.compareTo( current.element ) < 0 )
                current = current.left;
            else if( x.compareTo( current.element ) > 0 ) 
                current = current.right;
            else if( current != nullNode )
                return current.element;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make the tree logically empty.
     */
    public void makeEmpty( )
    {
        header.right = nullNode;
    }

    /**
     * Test if the tree is logically empty.
     * @return true if empty, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty( )
    {
        return header.right == nullNode;
    }

    /**
     * Print the tree contents in sorted order.
     */
    public void printTree( )
    {
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            System.out.println( "Empty tree" );
        else
            printTree( header.right );
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to print a subtree in sorted order.
     * @param t the node that roots the tree.
     */
    private void printTree( RedBlackNode t )
    {
        if( t != nullNode )
        {
            printTree( t.left );
            System.out.println( t.element );
            printTree( t.right );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Internal routine that is called during an insertion
     * if a node has two red children. Performs flip and rotations.
     * @param item the item being inserted.
     */
    private void handleReorient( Comparable item )
    {
            // Do the color flip
        current.color = RED;
        current.left.color = BLACK;
        current.right.color = BLACK;

        if( parent.color == RED )   // Have to rotate
        {
            grand.color = RED;
            if( ( item.compareTo( grand.element ) < 0 ) !=
                ( item.compareTo( parent.element ) < 0 ) )
                parent = rotate( item, grand );  // Start dbl rotate
            current = rotate( item, great );
            current.color = BLACK;
        }
        header.right.color = BLACK; // Make root black
    }

    /**
     * Internal routine that performs a single or double rotation.
     * Because the result is attached to the parent, there are four cases.
     * Called by handleReorient.
     * @param item the item in handleReorient.
     * @param parent the parent of the root of the rotated subtree.
     * @return the root of the rotated subtree.
     */
    private RedBlackNode rotate( Comparable item, RedBlackNode parent )
    {
        if( item.compareTo( parent.element ) < 0 )
            return parent.left = item.compareTo( parent.left.element ) < 0 ?
                rotateWithLeftChild( parent.left )  :  // LL
                rotateWithRightChild( parent.left ) ;  // LR
        else
            return parent.right = item.compareTo( parent.right.element ) < 0 ?
                rotateWithLeftChild( parent.right ) :  // RL
                rotateWithRightChild( parent.right );  // RR
    }

    /**
     * Rotate binary tree node with left child.
     */
    static RedBlackNode rotateWithLeftChild( RedBlackNode k2 )
    {
        RedBlackNode k1 = k2.left;
        k2.left = k1.right;
        k1.right = k2;
        return k1;
    }

    /**
     * Rotate binary tree node with right child.
     */
    static RedBlackNode rotateWithRightChild( RedBlackNode k1 )
    {
        RedBlackNode k2 = k1.right;
        k1.right = k2.left;
        k2.left = k1;
        return k2;
    }

    private RedBlackNode header;
    private static RedBlackNode nullNode;
        static         // Static initializer for nullNode
        {
            nullNode = new RedBlackNode( null );
            nullNode.left = nullNode.right = nullNode;
        }

    static final int BLACK = 1;    // Black must be 1
    static final int RED   = 0;

        // Used in insert routine and its helpers
    private static RedBlackNode current;
    private static RedBlackNode parent;
    private static RedBlackNode grand;
    private static RedBlackNode great;


        // Test program
    public static void main( String [ ] args )
    {
        RedBlackTree t = new RedBlackTree( new MyInteger( Integer.MIN_VALUE ) );
        final int NUMS = 40000;
        final int GAP  =   307;


        t.printTree(); 

        System.out.println( "Checking... (no more output means success)" );

        for( int i = GAP; i != 0; i = ( i + GAP ) % NUMS )
            t.insert( new MyInteger( i ) );

        if( NUMS < 40 )
            t.printTree( );
        if( ((MyInteger)(t.findMin( ))).intValue( ) != 1 ||
            ((MyInteger)(t.findMax( ))).intValue( ) != NUMS - 1 )
            System.out.println( "FindMin or FindMax error!" );

        for( int i = 1; i < NUMS; i++ )
             if( ((MyInteger)(t.find( new MyInteger( i ) ))).intValue( ) != i )
                 System.out.println( "Find error1!" );
    }
}
```

i should add items to the RedBlackTree and i should add a Comparable. It is the first time i have come accross this data type. What value should i pass in?

Answer (score 2):

Each object of type T stored in the Red black tree should implement the Comparable interface, meaning it should have a function like this:

```
int compareTo(T o) {
 //returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.
}
```

The purpose is to be able to have a basis of comparison for storing and location objects within the Red Black Tree. Simple objects like String or Integer are comparable by default, but you can also use the same data structure to store instances of any custom class, as long as it implements the Comparable interface.

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation for `java.lang.Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). In particular, see the list of "all known implementing classes" there. Popular ones include `String`, `Integer`, `Date`, and `Timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

`Comparable` is an interface which allows comparing objects of an implementing type. For example, for `Integer` you have the ordering -5 < -1 < 0 < 1 < 20 etc. Similarily, other numeric types such as `Long`, `Float` and `Double` are `Comparable` as are `Strings`s (lexicographical ordering). Since the tree is based on putting values which are in a certain ordering relationship to one another in the correct nodes, the type of value stored in the tree must be `Comparable` so that the ordering can be determined. You can also implement your own comparable types (the method `compareTo()` has to be overridden). Note that all elements in the tree should be of the same type, you can't e.g. mix `Integer` and `String` values.

In the constructor you show in your question, you need to pass a value which is smaller than any other value of your type. For `Integer`, this will be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, for `String` - `""` (the empty string). For custom types, you will need to invent one.